# Finding area of triangle? "Undefined" if num < 0

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

The objective is to find the area of a triangle. And if either base or height are < 0 it should return "undefined."

```
function calculateTriangleArea(base, height) {
  return base && height > 0 ? (base*height)/2 : "undefined"
}

console.log(calculateTriangleArea(2, 4)); // -> 4
console.log(calculateTriangleArea(-1, 3)); // -> -1.5
```

I want to use the ternary operator doing this.

Why does console.log(calculateTriangleArea(-1, 3)) not print "undefined?"

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank you, I see that fixes it:

```
return base > 0 && height > 0 ?
```

However why do I have to do that with this triangle and why could I lump numOne and numTwo together in a function to find the area of a rectangle:

```
function calculateRectangleArea(numOne, numTwo) {
  return numOne && numTwo > 0 ? numOne * numTwo : "undefined"
};
```

Comment: @Pang, you should really put this as a proper answer rather than answering the question in the comments. That way it can be marked as the accepted answer and people don't open this question thinking it hasn't been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check for greater than 0 for `base` also

```js
function calculateTriangleArea(base, height) {
  return base > 0 && height > 0 ? (base*height)/2 : "undefined"
}

function calculateRectangleArea(numOne, numTwo) {
  return numOne > 0 && numTwo > 0 ? numOne * numTwo : "undefined"
};

console.log(calculateTriangleArea(2, 4)); // -> 4
console.log(calculateTriangleArea(-1, 3)); // -> 'Undefined'

console.log(calculateRectangleArea(2, 4)); // -> 4
console.log(calculateRectangleArea(-1, 3)); // -> 'Undefined'
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Even for the rectangle area you have to do the same, otherwise you won't get 'undefined'

Comment: But when I  run the code, and:                            
    console.log(calculateRectangleArea(10, -5));                                                         Undefined, comes??

Comment: Yes , that is because you have the condition `numTwo > 0`, try doing this  `console.log(calculateRectangleArea(-1, 3));` with the same code

Comment: Yes. Yes. Thank you Senal. Greetings to Sri Lanka.

Comment: You have a check that `numTwo > 0` and numTwo is `-5`. What's missing is a check that `numOne > 0`. You won't get undefined for this: `console.log(calculateRectangleArea(-5,10));`